# How to remove I-beam character in header in Word

Tags: windows, windows-xp, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I have a weird I-beam character in my Word document header. How do I remove it? And no, it's not my mouse cursor ;)

[image: I-beam in Word header]

Comment: Which Microsoft Office version are you using? Also, what's the operating system?

Comment: I'm using MS Office Professional Plus 2010 (Word v. 14.0.6129.5000) on Windows XP.

Comment: Is this a `user form` created for people to fill in fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are bookmarks. To make it so they don't show, go to `File > Options > Advanced > Show Document Content` and uncheck the `Show bookmarks`.

[image]